# sorting flash overlap problem wmode='opaque'

Tags: php, flash, video, wmode, param

im trying to fix the flash overlap using regular expressions. here is an example of markup im trying to convert to my needs

```
  <object width="440" height="300" data=
  "http://www.youtube.com/v/dMH0bHeiRNg&amp;color1=0xb1b1b1&amp;color2=0xd0d0d0&amp;hl=en_US&amp;feature=player_embedded&amp;fs=1"
  type="application/x-shockwave-flash">
    <param name="allowScriptAccess" value="never" />
    <param name="allowNetworking" value="internal" />
    <param name="wmode" value="window" />
    <param name="movie" value=
    "http://www.youtube.com/v/dMH0bHeiRNg&amp;color1=0xb1b1b1&amp;color2=0xd0d0d0&amp;hl=en_US&amp;feature=player_embedded&amp;fs=1" />
    <!--[if IE]><embed width="440" height="300" src="http://www.youtube.com/v/dMH0bHeiRNg&amp;color1=0xb1b1b1&amp;color2=0xd0d0d0&amp;hl=en_US&amp;feature=player_embedded&amp;fs=1" allowScriptAccess="never" allowNetworking="internal" wmode="window"><![endif]-->
  </object>
```

i want a function using regluar expressions that
1) checks presence of `<param name="wmode" .....` if it exists... it forcefully sets value to 'opaque'. if doesn't exists it adds it to the above code.

I need this function to solve flash overlap problems of 'html' code saved in database

Comment: Why do you want to do this using regular expressions? It would be much cleaner and better using a DOM parser. (Although the IE conditional comment might get crunched by PHP's built in DOM parser.)

Comment: user input of embed code parsed and cleaned using html purifier. the parsed code is xhtml complaint and safe from XSS. i want the purified html to be forced to have that parameter if it exisits or not. do u have a DOM solution never used the dom parser, lemme read on it

Comment: i think this cud also be done with DOM parser, any one with a solution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i've found a pure JS function that fix it in all browsers!

there you go:

```
function fix_flash() {
    // loop through every embed tag on the site
    var embeds = document.getElementsByTagName('embed');
    for (i = 0; i < embeds.length; i++) {
        embed = embeds[i];
        var new_embed;
        // everything but Firefox & Konqueror
        if (embed.outerHTML) {
            var html = embed.outerHTML;
            // replace an existing wmode parameter
            if (html.match(/wmode\s*=\s*('|")[a-zA-Z]+('|")/i))
                new_embed = html.replace(/wmode\s*=\s*('|")window('|")/i, "wmode='transparent'");
            // add a new wmode parameter
            else
                new_embed = html.replace(/<embed\s/i, "<embed wmode='transparent' ");
            // replace the old embed object with the fixed version
            embed.insertAdjacentHTML('beforeBegin', new_embed);
            embed.parentNode.removeChild(embed);
        } else {
            // cloneNode is buggy in some versions of Safari & Opera, but works fine in FF
            new_embed = embed.cloneNode(true);
            if (!new_embed.getAttribute('wmode') || new_embed.getAttribute('wmode').toLowerCase() == 'window')
                new_embed.setAttribute('wmode', 'transparent');
            embed.parentNode.replaceChild(new_embed, embed);
        }
    }
    // loop through every object tag on the site
    var objects = document.getElementsByTagName('object');
    for (i = 0; i < objects.length; i++) {
        object = objects[i];
        var new_object;
        // object is an IE specific tag so we can use outerHTML here
        if (object.outerHTML) {
            var html = object.outerHTML;
            // replace an existing wmode parameter
            if (html.match(/<param\s+name\s*=\s*('|")wmode('|")\s+value\s*=\s*('|")[a-zA-Z]+('|")\s*\/?\>/i))
                new_object = html.replace(/<param\s+name\s*=\s*('|")wmode('|")\s+value\s*=\s*('|")window('|")\s*\/?\>/i, "<param name='wmode' value='transparent' />");
            // add a new wmode parameter
            else
                new_object = html.replace(/<\/object\>/i, "<param name='wmode' value='transparent' />\n</object>");
            // loop through each of the param tags
            var children = object.childNodes;
            for (j = 0; j < children.length; j++) {
                try {
                    if (children[j] != null) {
                        var theName = children[j].getAttribute('name');
                        if (theName != null && theName.match(/flashvars/i)) {
                            new_object = new_object.replace(/<param\s+name\s*=\s*('|")flashvars('|")\s+value\s*=\s*('|")[^'"]*('|")\s*\/?\>/i, "<param name='flashvars' value='" + children[j].getAttribute('value') + "' />");
                        }
                    }
                }
                catch (err) {
                }
            }
            // replace the old embed object with the fixed versiony
            object.insertAdjacentHTML('beforeBegin', new_object);
            object.parentNode.removeChild(object);
        }
    }
}
```

now you can just run in when the page loads with jQuery:

```
 $(document).ready(function () {
            fix_flash();    
 }
```

Answer (score 1):

I fixed it by calling this function(below) within $(document).ready function.

```
window.fix_wmode2transparent_swf = function  () {
    // For embed
    jQuery("embed").each(function(i) {
        var elClone = this.cloneNode(true);
        elClone.setAttribute("WMode", "Transparent");
        jQuery(this).before(elClone);
        jQuery(this).remove();
    });    
    // For object and/or embed into objects
    jQuery("object").each(function (i, v) {
    var elEmbed = jQuery(this).children("embed");
    if(typeof (elEmbed.get(0)) != "undefined") {
        if(typeof (elEmbed.get(0).outerHTML) != "undefined") {
            elEmbed.attr("wmode", "transparent");
            jQuery(this.outerHTML).insertAfter(this);
            jQuery(this).remove();
        }
        return true;
    }
    var algo = this.attributes;
    var str_tag = '<OBJECT ';
    for (var i=0; i < algo.length; i++) str_tag += algo[i].name + '="' + algo[i].value + '" ';    
    str_tag += '>';
    var flag = false;
    jQuery(this).children().each(function (elem) {
        if(this.nodeName == "PARAM") {
            if (this.name == "wmode") {
                flag=true;
                str_tag += '<PARAM NAME="' + this.name + '" VALUE="transparent">';        
            }
            else  str_tag += '<PARAM NAME="' + this.name + '" VALUE="' + this.value + '">';
        }
    });
    if(!flag)
        str_tag += '<PARAM NAME="wmode" VALUE="transparent">';        
    str_tag += '</OBJECT>';
    jQuery(str_tag).insertAfter(this);
    jQuery(this).remove();    
    });
}
```

source

http://www.nobilesoft.com/Scripts/fix_wmode2transparent_swf.js

Answer (score 1):

There is a mistake in your code. With fix, it is working excellent. The code will be

```
$(document).ready(function () {
            fix_flash();    
});
```